# Serverless WSGI Local Server Running Slow

Tags: python, wsgi, serverless-framework, werkzeug

Im using the node package [serverless-wsgi](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serverless-wsgi) 1.4.9 to serve the routes of my [serverless framework](https://serverless.com/) application

When I run by dev server `serverless wsgi serve` I'm having problems with the requests taking a long time (10seconds - 1min) to return a response in chrome. To avoid hitting a database I'm sending GET request to a route that immediately returns 'hello world' 200.

So far the only predictable behaviour I can find is that making a request using jquery will always cause a long delay before returning. If I try to request the same URL in the browser tab (whilst the jquery request is still waiting) the tab also waits a long time for for the request to return.

However, once the jquery request returns, calling the URL in a browser tab then returns immediately. Refreshing the tab gives a response immediately.

Sometimes, if jquery request is pending, calling the URL in a browser tab WILL return immediately. When this happens, this seem to also make the jquery request return a response.

Jquery code below:

```
  $( document ).ready(function() {
    $.get("http://localhost:5000/test", function(data, status){
      alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    });
  });
```

I've tried restarting the server, browsers and my machine, but the problem still persists.

I've tried multiple browsers (safari, chrome, firefox) and all have the same issue.

I've tried making a javascript request using axios instead of jquery but still the requests are returning slowly.

Does anyone have any idea how I might solve this or any additional debugging I can do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this is mainly a problem with chrome and the way chrome uses preconnections

https://hackernoon.com/chrome-preconnect-breaks-singly-threaded-servers-95944be16400

The way to solve this is to set the WSGI server to allow threading. I have [raised an issue](https://github.com/logandk/serverless-wsgi/issues/69) with the team as its currently not possible to do this if you are using `serverless-wsgi`.

As a work around, you can turn off the preconnection feature in chrome. Go to *Settings > Advanced > Privacy and security* and turn off *Use a prediction service to load pages more quickly*. This is now in *Settings > Cookies and other site data > Preload pages for faster browsing and searching* in [more recent versions](https://www.ghacks.net/2019/04/23/missing-chromes-use-a-prediction-service-setting/) of Chrome.